# bootstrap modal wont open on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

My bootstrap modal wont open on page load I do not know why.
The button to open the modal works tho.

My code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    window.onload = function() {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case may be already answered thousand times, but consider few these causes:

1. Order of your libraries, are they in correct position?
2. Perhaps you forget to include bootstrap.js
3. Consider to include popper.js
   Please let me know, if it helps

Comment: Thank you, That was the order of the libraries. I had old ones probably, switched to the newest ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it works for me. it is built with bootstrap 5.1:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```